# CameraX with MediaCodec

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, androidx, android-camerax

I am building a video streaming application that would send recorded video in real time to the network.

I want to use CameraX API (yes, I know it is experimental) and convert the video stream in real time into some codec using MediaCodec, then get the output and send it on its way.

I tried to use Preview use-case for this: `preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener` passes a `Preview.PreviewOutput` as an argument to the listener. I can extract surface texture from it using: `output.getSurfaceTexture()`.

```
preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                (Preview.PreviewOutput output) -> 
                        mSurfaceTexture = output.getSurfaceTexture());
```

MediaCodec provides me with a `Surface` that I can write into, however I could not find any effective way of copying the contents of `mSurfaceTexture` into `mediaCodec.createInputSurface()`.

Is there any way of doing this without messing with OpenGL? Or any other way to pass data from CameraX capture into MediaCodec (ImageAnalysis, VideoCapture)?

Comment: Have you connected cameraX with MediaCodec?

Comment: Any improvements on this?